# Allow background-image url to be clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background-image

Is there a way to allow this (search) icon to be clickable? I would like it so that it can be used as an expand/collapse button for the list below it. The list is html and I can hide and show it. I'm more curious as to how I would allow the icon to be clickable to be able to hide/show the ul/li list. If this is possible, can an animation be applied somehow. This is a sample from w3 schools, but I have my own data. Should I convert it into a different type of list? There are examples online of retractable lists with animations as well.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";

        }
    }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('https://www.w3schools.com/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><br>
<div>
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
</div>

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: which icon do you want to make clickable, what exactly do you want to happen when clicked and what have you tried so far?

Comment: You want to click on the Icon, and expand/collapse the list below it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make clickable any DOM element by adding an **event listener**. In your example the icon is a background image of the `input` element, so you need to remove it from there and make it an independent image to interact with it. Then you can add the event listener to click, triggering a function to show / hide the list (I changed the css to start hidden).

```js
var searchIco = document.getElementById("search-ico");
var myUL = document.getElementById("myUL");
searchIco.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if(myUL.style.display == 'block') {
    myUL.style.display = 'none';
    // or: myUL.removeAttribute("style");
  } else {
    myUL.style.display = 'block';
  }
});

function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";

        }
    }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* New */
#search-ico {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}
/* Background removed, size changed */
#myInput {
  width: 80%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#myUL {
  display: none; /* Added to start hidden */
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><br>
<div>
<!-- Add the icon as a separate image -->
<img id="search-ico" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/searchicon.png">
<!-- end of edited -->
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
</div>

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Great. Thanks so much. It seems like you cannot do much with a background-image but never mind, your answer works great.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the slideToggle function based on jQuery (since you are already using jQuery)

```
  $('#myInput').click(function(){
    $('#myUL').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Learn more about sideToggle here - http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/